# Trigger window.print() two or more times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which contains, let's say 3 divs which I want to print seperatly - and I can do that manually. However, the webapp is running Chrome with silent printing and I need to print these 3 divs, in 3 seperate print jobs. A print stylesheet is not what I need - 3 SEPERATE PRINT JOBS IS NEEDED...

So I need to trigger window.print() multiple times. The best and only solution I have come up with is trigger my print function 3 times, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { printContent('print1', 'letter'); }, 0);

setTimeout(function() { printContent('print2', 'letter'); }, 1);

setTimeout(function() { printContent('print3', 'letter'); }, 2);
```

However, somethimes Chrome fails to run the function three times. How can I make sure, that the function is triggered corretly 3 times in a row?

Should anyone find it interesting, my printContent() function is this:

```
function printContent(divContent, divClass) {
    var divContent = $('#' + divContent).html();
    $('#print-spooler-box').html('').addClass(divClass).html(divContent);
    window.print();
    $('#print-spooler-box').removeClass(divClass);
}
```

Comment: I've never done this task this way before, but you could try using a longer delay. Like 100-250ms between each print call. It may give the print subsystem enough time to process one before the next one is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid printing multiple times, by editing your print CSS.

You can use a media query, or the `media` attribute (in a `<link>` element) to target print styles.

```
<div class="new-page">
  <p>page one</p>
</div>
<div class="new-page">
  <p>page two</p>
</div>
```

and then in your CSS:

```
.new-page{
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

Comment: Yep I know - but no matter what, in my case I need seperate print jobs. This is due to the fact that I want to allow the user to only print specific parts of the page and not force the user to print all elements visible in print stylesheet. Second, and most important, sometimes the printer used is a thermal printer - the cutter on the thermal printer is only activated, when the print jobs are split up.
That is why I wrote "I need to print these 3 divs, in 3 seperate print jobs." :)

Comment: Then you'll need 3 separate print buttons with show/hide of relevant elements. Users *do* have the ability to choose which page to print in the print dialog you know...

Comment: Don't want to use show/hide - and yes I need different print buttons, but not nescessarily with show/hide of relevant elements ... I'll load the desired content into my div for printing. It's much more flexible, than writing print-stylesheets to show/hide elements or use jQuery to show/hide relevant elements. And like I said, I need seperate print jobs to active the cutter on a thermal printer. It cannot be achieved with a stylesheet.